# Ошибка с выводом результата в функциях

Tags: python, функции

Текст задачи: Сгенерировать десять списков из случайных чисел.

- Вывести их и сумму их элементов на экран.
- Найти среди них один с максимальной суммой элементов.
- Указать какой он по счету, повторно вывести этот список и сумму его элементов.
- Заполнение списка и подсчет суммы его элементов оформить в виде отдельных функций.

Теперь, собственно, о проблеме: в первой функции (смотрите ниже код) у меня идёт заполнение 10 списков, во второй функции производится нахождение суммы в 10-ти списках, но у меня генерируется новые 10 списков, а мне нужно работать с результатом полученным в первой, то есть со старыми списками...

Вопрос: как это исправить?

Проблема №2: я не знаю как вывести повторно список с максимальной суммой элементов и сам список

```
import random

n = int(input("Введите кол-во возможных случайных:"))
b = int(input("Введите диапазон случайных значений:"))

def func_1(n, b):
    d = [[random.randrange(b) for i in range(n)] for i in range(10)]
    print("Исходные 10 списков:", d)

func_1(n, b)

def func_2(n, b):
    d = [[sum(random.randrange(b) for i in range(n))] for i in range(10)]
    print("сумма элементов в каждом из 10 списков:", d)
    return d 

func_2(n, b)

d = func_2(n, b)
g = max(d)
c = len(d)

for i in range(c):
    if d[i] == g:
        print("Номер максимального элемента:", g, i)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Старайтесь оформлять функции таким образом, чтобы они возвращали интересующие вас значения, а не просто печатали их на экран.

```
import random

def gen_list(n,b):
    return [random.randrange(b) for i in range(n)]

def sum_list(lst):
    return sum(lst)

N = 5
n = 10
b = 100    
lists = [gen_list(n,b) for _ in range(N)]

print(lists)
#[[31, 2, 61, 28, 85, 36, 7, 81, 40, 71],
# [13, 59, 66, 52, 54, 75, 23, 66, 66, 23],
# [50, 16, 99, 74, 82, 94, 32, 30, 70, 7],
# [27, 88, 87, 15, 58, 86, 71, 47, 27, 29],
# [27, 43, 74, 7, 60, 68, 75, 69, 77, 57]]

print([sum_list(l) for l in lists])
#[442, 497, 554, 535, 557]

idx_max = max(enumerate(lists), key=lambda x: sum_list(x[1]))[0]
print(f'Max list: {lists[idx_max]}\nsum(max_list): {sum_list(lists[idx_max])}')
#Max list: [27, 43, 74, 7, 60, 68, 75, 69, 77, 57]
#sum(max_list): 557
```

Comment: объясните пожалуйста print([sum_list(l) for l in lists])

Comment: @Noob_Prog, здесь используется “list comprehension” , чтобы напечатать суммы внутренних списков

Comment: благодарю за решение

Comment: lists = [gen_list(n,b) for _ in range(N)]у объясните зачем нужен знак подчёркивания здесь?

Comment: Подчёркивание используют в качестве «ненужной» переменной. Здесь можно было использовать любое свободное имя переменной. Эта переменная нигде не используется и нужна для итерирование по “range()”.

Comment: lists = [gen_list(n,b) for _ in range(N)] за что отвечает это строка ?

Comment: за создание матрицы (списка списков - `lists`)